# iOS 6, Segue: prepareForSegue doesn't get called when tapping on UITableViewCell at first time

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard, segue

I've got an issue with segues. My UITableViewController has two segues to other UITableViewControllers. The segues linked from controller to controller, not from cell to controller.

code:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueOne"])
{
    //implementation omitted
}
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueTwo"])
{
   //implementation omitted
}
}
```

The evil place:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(self.navigationKey==1)
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueOne" sender:self];

}
if(self.navigationKey==2 || self.navigationKey==3)
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueTwo" sender:self];
}
}
```

Generally, the navigation works. Definitely, the problem is that navigation doesn't work on firstly selected cell. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Then why it does at second tap on other cell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using tableView:did**Deselect**RowAtIndexPath:

instead of

tableView:did**Select**RowAtIndexPath:

Hope this helps,